# Seeking marriage record of John McGrady and Elizabeth McDonald in Ireland about 1885?

Tags: marriage-records, ireland, 1880s

John McGrady born approximately 1860, married Elizabeth McDonald, (on her birth cert but later written Elizabeth O'Donnell) in approx 1885. Proni does not have a record of this marriage. She was born in Lisburn ( I have her birth cert) and he is born in Belfast according to the 1901 census. They lived in Belfast and later Dublin.

1. Apart from PRONI where else can I search?
2. Did she need her marriage cert to get an OAPension and can I see it if she produced it for Social Welfare?

Comment: Have you tried IrishGenealogy.ie? There's a John O'Grady Elizabeth McDonald marriage in Dublin in Dublin in 1889. This site is free even for events in what became Northern Ireland but obviously NI events only go up to 1922. There's not enough detail in your question for me to know if that marriage is possible or not.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  How did you arrive at your approximate marriage date?

Comment: Their first child Hugh McGrady was born in 1887. I have the birth and baptismal records of all their children

Comment: I cannot find the record you refer to Adrian. I was expecting the marriage would take place in Northern Ireland as all the Birth and baptismal records are in Belfast. Also he is an electrician and plumber with his own company and I can follow the family as it moves around in the civil and RC records and his business address in the Belfast commercial directory.